# Call function after getting response from WS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services

I need to call three WS services before calling a local function depending on whether some variables are defined or not, but the function is getting called before the services get any response, because it could take some time. I've even tried with $timeout, but it does not work

```
    $scope.$on('search', function (event, data) {
                self.searchDto= data;
                if (self.searchDto.userCode) {
                    self.searchByUserCode(self.searchDto.userCode).then(function (data) {
                        self.userCode= data.find(function (item) {
                            return item.mstId === self.searchDto.userCode;
                        });
                    });
                }

                if (self.searchDto.companyCode) {
                    self.serachByCompanyCode(self.searchDto.companyCode).then(function (data) {
                        self.companyCode= data.find(function (item) {
                            return item.mstId === self.searchDto.companyCode;
                        });
                    });
                } 

                if (self.searchDto.jobCode) {
                    self.searchByJobCode(self.searchDto.jobCode).then(function (data) {
                        self.jobCode= data.find(function (item) {
                            return item.mstId === self.searchDto.jobCode;
                        });
                    });
                } 

//I tried with this timeout but it didnt work
                $timeout(function () {
                     self.searchPeople();
                }, 1000);
            });
```

Does anyone have idea how the searchPeople method can be called after the WS responses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [promises](https://dwmkerr.com/promises-in-angularjs-the-definitive-guide/) and `$q.all()`

```
var promises = [];
promises.push(self.searchByUserCode(self.searchDto.userCode).then(function (data) {
                        self.userCode= data.find(function (item) {
                            return item.mstId === self.searchDto.userCode;
                        });
                    }));
```

`.then()` returns a promise. Do that for the 3 service calls and then wait for their completion

```
$q.all(promises).then(function(){
    self.searchPeople();
})
```

I see that you might not call all of your services. `$q.all()` will wait for the promise you put in the array. Keep in mind it will also execute your call if none of your services has been executed, if you need at least one to be called, you might want to add a check for `promises.length > 0` before `$q.all()`.

That way, if you only call one of your services, the promises array will have one element and upon its completion, will call your local function.

Answer (score 0):

Setting timeout is not a correct approaching here. One solution can be: you should put 3 WS nested and put the function call inside the last WS callback.
  It also depends on how much arguments that your `searchPeople` need. If it only work with fully 3 arguments from WS calls, another solution is putting the function call in all 3 WS callback, and inside function `searchPeople`, you should add a condition statement to check if we have fully 3 argument before do searching

Comment: The thing is that, it could be called all of them or none, when none of the three parameters is defined searchPeople is called without any problem, so I dont think those solutions could help me out, If I do it nested, if the first parameter is not defined, so the other wont be called even if they are, and the second because as I said before, none of them could be sent